# Return bin coordinates python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, append

I have a `scatter plot` that gets sorted into `bins`. There are 4 bins, two arcs separated by a line in the middle. It's sorted row by row into a list of lists. E.g. If there's one scatter point in each bin the export would be:

```
x[0],y[0] = [(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)]
```

The problem is I have to manually export each row. So If I wanted to export the second row of scatter plot I would change to `x[1],y[1]` and add it to the 1st row. This isn't very efficient if I have multiple rows.

If I use `x,y` I get a Value Error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (70,) (10,)`

Is there a method to export the entire dataset row by row or alternatively, use the same code and loop through each row.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))
y = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)

plt.scatter(x[0],y[0])

#Creating the arcs
BIN_23_X = 50 
ang1 = 0, 50
ang2 = 100, 50
angle = math.degrees(math.acos(5.5/9.15))

#Adding the arcs and halfway line
Halfway = mpl.lines.Line2D((BIN_23_X,BIN_23_X), (0,100), c = 'black', lw = 2.5, alpha = 0.8, zorder = 1)
arc1 = mpl.patches.Arc(ang1, 65, 100, angle = 0, theta2 = angle, theta1 = 360-angle, lw = 2)
arc2 = mpl.patches.Arc(ang2, 65, 100, angle = 0, theta2 = 180+angle, theta1 = 180-angle, lw = 2)

ax.add_line(Halfway)
ax.add_patch(arc1)
ax.add_patch(arc2)

#Sorting the coordinates into bins   
def get_nearest_arc_vert(x, y, arc_vertices):
    err = (arc_vertices[:,0] - x)**2 + (arc_vertices[:,1] - y)**2
    nearest = (arc_vertices[err == min(err)])[0]
    return nearest

arc1v = ax.transData.inverted().transform(arc1.get_verts())
arc2v = ax.transData.inverted().transform(arc2.get_verts())

def classify_pointset(vx, vy):
    bins = {(k+1):[] for k in range(4)}
    for (x,y) in zip(vx, vy):
        nx1, ny1 = get_nearest_arc_vert(x, y, arc1v)
        nx2, ny2 = get_nearest_arc_vert(x, y, arc2v)

        if x < nx1:                         
            bins[1].append((x,y))
        elif x > nx2:                      
            bins[4].append((x,y))
        else:
            if x < BIN_23_X:               
                bins[2].append((x,y))
            else:                          
                bins[3].append((x,y))
    return bins

#Bins Output
bins_red  = classify_pointset(x[0], y[0])

all_points = [None] * 5
for bin_key in [1,2,3,4]:
    all_points[bin_key] = bins_red[bin_key] 

print(all_points)
```

The row that I want to sort into bins is:

```
bins = classify_pointset(x[0], y[0])
```

Can I change the `bins = classify_pointset(x[0], y[0])` or add a loop to iterate through each row?

***EXAMPLE OF WHAT I'M HOPING TO ACCOMPLISH***

If we use the first row of the data to return the binned coordinates I would use:

```
bins = classify_pointset(x[0], y[0])
```

Output:

```
[None, [(17, 20), (20, 36), (23, 30), (0, 65), (15, 35)], [(44, 57), (45, 3), (43, 0)], [(61, 21)], [(78, 23)]]
```

[image]

As you can see there's 5 coordinates in the 1st bin `[(17, 20), (20, 36), (23, 30), (0, 65), (15, 35)]`. 3 in the 2nd `[(44, 57), (45, 3), (43, 0)]`, 1 in the 3rd bin `[(61, 21)]` and 1 in the 4th bin `[(78, 23)]`

To return the 2nd row of binned coordinates I would change:

`bins = classify_pointset(x[0], y[0])` to `bins = classify_pointset(x[1], y[1])`.

I would then append the 2nd row to the first row to create this:

```
0 = [(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)]
1 = [(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)]
```

This problem is I have to keep manually changing the row and appending. E.g

Return `bins = classify_pointset(x[2], y[2])` and then append:

Output:

```
2 = [(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)]
```

Append:

```
0 = [(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)]
1 = [(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)]
2 = [(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)],[(x,y)]
```

I need something that returns the entire xy dataset into their respective bins in a row by row format. Instead of exporting one row at a time and then appending.

Doe this make sense?

Comment: `#Coordinates get sorted into bins to produce a dict` Is your question how do we bin without `dict`? In which case, what is your binning logic?

Comment: Whatever you use for binning, can you bin into a list of dicts, i.e. instead of `d_1strow` have `d_bins[0]` etc.? Then just loop over that list.

Comment: @jpp I've changed it to a list of lists and added the binning methodology

Comment: @tobias_k, Will this go in the `if` statement or can it come afterwards?

Comment: I'm going to look into this, but could you give an example of some input and what the corresponding output would be?

Comment: Sure @David. Thanks

Comment: This makes sense. Could you provide an X and a Y to test on? You've given an output, but not the corresponding input. It's late here so I can look at this in the morning.

Comment: If you cope the code above you'll get an example output for the scatter and bins.                                                                                                                     `x = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))
y = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))`                                                              is the example xy dataset

Comment: Yes, but the X,Y values change every run. Not very conducive to testing.

Comment: Hey, you should accept my answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is my stab at this. There are a few things that I'm unsure why you chose to do it that way so I've changed them. Feel free to let know if they needed to be that way, and I can change them back.

First, I'm not sure why you use a dictionary instead of a list for your bins in classify_pointset. I've changed it to use a list and it is now zero-indexed.

```
def classify_pointset(vx, vy):                                                                       
    bins = [[] for k in range(4)]                                                                    
    for (x,y) in zip(vx, vy):                                                                        
        nx1, ny1 = get_nearest_arc_vert(x, y, arc1v)                                                 
        nx2, ny2 = get_nearest_arc_vert(x, y, arc2v)                                                 

        if x < nx1:                                                                                  
            bins[0].append((x,y))                                                                    
        elif x > nx2:                                                                                
            bins[3].append((x,y))                                                                    
        else:                                                                                        
            if x < BIN_23_X:                                                                         
                bins[1].append((x,y))                                                                
            else:                                                                                    
                bins[2].append((x,y))                                                                

    return bins
```

Next, I'm not sure why you are then turning the dictionary that you did have into a list. The changes that I made above accomplish this.

Now for going through each bin automatically, we can just use the range function and the shape of the arrays. I am calculating the first bin manually just so that we can compare it against the final bins and make sure that it matches.

```
first_bin = classify_pointset(x[0],y[0])                                                             

#Bins Output                                                                                         
all_points = []                                                                                      

for i in range(x.shape[0]):                                                                          
    bins = classify_pointset(x[i],y[i])                                                              
    all_points.append(bins)                                                                          

print first_bin                                                                                      
print all_points[0]
```

Any code that isn't listen above was left as is. Let me know if anything is off or unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot David!